# Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $f$ belong to $C(K)$. Find spectrum of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $f$ belong to $C(K)$, where $C(K)$ is continuous functions on a compact interval. Find spectrum of $f$.

Proof-

$$\operatorname{Sp}(f)= \{a\in\mathbb C\mid a-f \text{ is not invertible} \} $$

where $\mathbb C$ is complex numbers.

We know that inverse of $a-f$ is $ \frac{1}{a-f}$. If $ \frac{1}{a-f}$ is not continuous then can we say $a-f$ is not invertible. My goal here is to find such 'a' values which makes $ \frac{1}{a-f}$ not invertible. I'm stuck in here.

Is my path correct?

Comment: It would seem to be significant if $a$ is in the range of $f$. And maybe not a problem otherwise. Some version of the result is covered in many books on spectral theory. Arveson is a good introduction.